# Involutary cipher (like ROT13) for an alphabet with an odd number of symbols

Tags: language-agnostic, function, math, encryption, rot13

ROT13 has the nice property of being an involution for an A-Z alphabet (26 letters), that is to say:

```
ROT13(ROT13(string-A-to-Z)) = string-A-to-Z ;
```

What is a simple cipher function for an alphabet with an *odd* number of symbols that has the same property? Obviously, a straight-up substitution won't work, but I'm looking for something nearly as simple.

Comment: Another way of putting it is that ROT13 is a pairing: it takes each letter to its partner. For this to work, the number of letters must be even.

Comment: You can simple have one uncommon character which stays itself during encryption.

Comment: The only nice property of ROT13 I can think of is the ease with which it can get you moderated +1 Funny on a certain nerd forum...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either exclude one of the symbols in the alphabet from the cipher, or supplement it with a symbol not in the alphabet.

Comment: Damn, I was seriously over-thinking this thing. *Back to work...*

Answer (score 2):

Such a cipher is necessarily the product of disjoint transpositions, so if you had an odd number of letters, one would have to remain in place.

Answer (score 1):

You could "reverse" the alphabet, switching `A` with `Z` and `B` with `Y` etc.

Comment: If you look at this another way, it still "excludes" one letter from the cypher, since the reversed alphabet will match the original at the "middle" letter. (Consider for example the alphabet 123; reversing it gets you 321, so ciphered the 2 is still a 2.)

Comment: @Tim: There really isn't any reason why every symbol would need to be mapped to a different one. As long as the attacker doesn't know the cipher she won't know if any symbols/which symbols are unchanged.

Comment: Absolutely - I just wanted to point out the correlation to Ignacio's answer above.